# How to store file object to mysql database using php

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I tried to store file to database:
I tried this:

```
 <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="2000000">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <input name="userfile" type="file" id="userfile" >
    </div>

 <input type="button" class="btn btn-success col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-1"
            style="width: 10%" value="Submit" id=ctl_submit title="Submit">
```

I get file object by doing this:

```
 $('#userfile')[0].files[0]
```

but how to process this object in php to store into DB. My DB contains these fields : filename, filecontent, filesize, filetype.
Can anyone please tell me?

Comment: not a good idea to store a file in database. Just store the file path in it, where your file is physically present on your server

Comment: @Sameer, Thanks for reply but it's client request to store file into database.

Comment: http://www.php-mysql-tutorial.com/wikis/mysql-tutorials/uploading-files-to-mysql-database.aspx  i guess this will help then

Comment: @Sameer, is there any other solution to get values from file object in php. Please Help?

Answer (score 0):

After submit a form you must have a $_FILES object. Which contains all the file related information like size type etc. So you can use that.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but when I alert the value of object I got this [Object File], then what to do with $_files, How I manage [Object File] with $_files?